# Kotlin - Mockito when using object equality instead of checking reference

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

Lets assume we have following method I want to write unit test for using `Mockito`

```
fun myMethod(
        param1: String,
        param2: Int
    ): List<ResultObject> {
        // Method is simplified for better understanding the problem
        val inputObject = InputObject(
            param1,
            param2
        )
        return someOtherService.someMethod(inputObject)
}

open class InputObject(
    val param1: String,
    val param2: Int
)
```

So unit test looks like this:

```
... class test setup (Mock, InjectMocks, ExtendWith, ...) omitted for simplicity
@Test
fun `it should work`() {
    val inputObject = InputObject("SOME_PARAM", 0)
    whenever(someOtherService.someMethod(inputObject)).thenReturn(...some mocked data...)

    assertThat(myTestedObject.myMethod("SOME_PARAM", 0)).isNotNull // Some assertion
}
```

But problem is, I am getting Mockito error telling me, that **object references for mocking someMethod are not the same** (and I get why, two separate `inputObjects` are created, one in tested method and one in the test itself, and therefore when Mockito comparing object references, it does not know what to do with this situation).

I´ve tried to wrap `inputObject` into `eq(inputObject)` but that did not work either.

**Is there any easy way to tell Mockito that I want it to check object content when trying to mock calling instead of comparing just references?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make `InputObject` a data class. Or make it implement equals/hashcode, so mockito can match the parameter on the mocked method.

Alternatively you could use an Answer ([1](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-methods#answer), [2](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-methods#answer)) and verify there that InputObject has the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the problem:

`whenever(someOtherService.someMethod(inputObject)).thenReturn(...`

What happen here is that you are "registering" a parameter for the `someMethod` method.  In complex tests you may wish to register several inputs and have the mocking framework return different objects depending on the input.  The matching is not working on `InputObject` probably because it is doing a reference check.  As @Augusto points out, you may be able to trivially solve this by changing `InputObject` to a `data class`.  If you cannot, and because this is really solving the wrong problem, I have written an alternate answer.

In most practical cases we don't care about the input to mock calls like `someMethod`, and want to return the same object for every invocation (or more likely there is only ever one invocation).

For this Mockito provides an `any()` methods which is a wildcard.  The java version of Mockito has had this for years. So you need this:

`whenever(someOtherService.someMethod(any())).thenReturn(listOf<ResultObject>())`

But this fails with a new error: `Parameter specified as non-null is null: method clinic.resethealth.OtherService.someMethod, parameter inputObject`.

Here you are suffering form Kotlin's strict rules on nulls.  And the Mockito-Kotlin port (which I presume you are using) recognises this and says it caters for it: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki but I could not coerce it to work.

---

At risk of getting myself awarded a down vote, I am going to offer you an alternative that does work, but by moving away from Mockito to a Kotlin-first library which achieves all the same things with methods/matchers you'll recognise from Mockito. That is **[mockk](https://mockk.io/)**.  (I have no affiliation).

Here is the test class working as you want:

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class InputObjectTest2 {

    @Test
    fun `it should work`() {
        val someOtherService = mockk<OtherService>()
        val myTestedObject = MyService(someOtherService)

        every { someOtherService.someMethod(any()) } returns listOf<ResultObject>()
        Assertions.assertNotNull( myTestedObject.myMethod("SOME_PARAM", 0))
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to share that as I rule of thumb I try to avoid `any*` methods as much as possible, as they can hide errors (for example in this case, an `InputObject` which was instantiated with incorrect values). If the classes and functions are designed with testing in mind, the only valid use of `any*` is to signal that a the value is irrelevant for a given test/mock. I'm sharing this as I'm currently refactoring a project that has abused `any`, and thus the tests have very little value.